# PHP get max. 1000 entries from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

So my problem is the following:

I am developing a WordPress plugin, and i am getting values from a custom database table. Lets call the table devices. From the device table, i am now getting all entries from the colum ids. But there is my problem: If this colum has more then 1000 entries, i need the "split" them, i mean, i need first to get the first 1000 entries, then the next 1000 until i reach the end. Any ideas how to do this in php?

For example, this is how i get the ids now:

```
function hlp_getIds() {
 global $wpdb;
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'devices';
 $devices = array();
 $sql = "SELECT id FROM $table_name";
 $res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
 if ($res != false) {
     foreach($res as $row){
         array_push($devices, $row->id);
     }
  }
  return $devices;
}
```

So how can i integrate a method to get only each 1000 entries and not all the entries at once?

Comment: Google `"pagination"`

Comment: You may also find `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` useful in the query - it'll allow you to find out how many records would be returned if the `LIMIT` wasn't there (using `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`) - it's a fairly nice way to work out if you're on the "last page" or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `limit`

```
select id 
from device 
order by id
limit 0, 1000
```

to get the next 1000 do

```
select id 
from device 
order by id
limit 1000, 1000
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but how can i do it inside a loop?

Comment: Use a PHP variable for the limit value `limit $offset, 1000` and the `$offset` starts from `0`